# Can I resign just after a week of start date? I feel overqualified with my job. Details below

Tags: new-job, quitting, reputation

I am recent science graduate. I am now employed with this insurance company just this week as a clerk in actuarial department. I thought through this, I can be promoted into a real actuary. This is the ONLY reason why I accepted the job in the first place. I asked my manager since I am not a math grad but science grad with a lot of maths maybe they can consider me on being an actuary and after all, they require no experience and fresh grads. He told me today that **they DO NOT ACCEPT NON-MATH grads** and made it clear that I wont be promoted with this position. It is a let down so I thought and made myself up today that I will not be staying since I dont wanna be just a clerk with my degree. I don't see any more reasons to stay in the company because:

Pros:

1. Office hours- non shifting which I like
2. People are easy to get along

Cons:

1. Very low salary
2. Very far from home
3. Unpleasant toilets- there are no free tissues or some bloody hand soap
4. Small office
5. Will stay as a clerk forever which Im pretty sure I would never wanna do
6. Not seeing myself improve in any way professionally and my maths are getting rusty and would defo will get rustier.

With these I had no second thoughts of resigning. I would like to tell my HR I would be resigning but have from the contract I have to work for 30 days before they pull me out. Id like to tell her that I would like a job more suitable to my qualifications. **I also would like to point put that I am pretty sure am very overqualified by just being a clerk and I will not be able to use my skills in there.** I know lots of basic programming languages, have decent grades, speaks multiple language, very good in math.

**My question now if this is possible and what are the risk that I am taking? Would it reflect my reputation in a bad way?** I really dont think I can stand on compiling bloody files and photocopy and staple documents! *I really really need ur professional advises I dont know what to do. I am very new on the workplace.*

Comment: voting to close as off topic - "Rather than explaining why your situation is terrible, or why your boss/coworker makes you unhappy, explain what you want to do to make it better"

Comment: How is this off topic? I am new btw. I already asked what my chances are to be on the position  I want and he told me they cant give me that job. I am asking for possible risks here and what steps should I do as this is my first job.

Comment: @JackD.Ripper - we can't advise on what to do, only give advice on what you are thinking of doing.  e.g. you could resign and get another different job, resign and try and get the job you thought you were getting, get the job then resign, get the qualifications you need to progress etc.  You need to think of what the options are, then we can feedback on them.

Comment: That was what I was asking @The Wandwering. I just need thoughts and professional advice. I find ur answer insufficient. I was asking what risks im taking and stuff

Comment: @Joe No and that is I admit my stupidity. I didnt even know that my salary was on minimum until I saw the contract. I didnt ask much as I dont wanna hurt my chances.It served as a lesson to me

Comment: "I am very new on the workplace" - maybe this is part of the reason you're getting non-challenging assignments. Finish your current assignments and then make it clear that you want and can do things more challenging with your skills.

Comment: @Joe im aware of that now. but I want to prepare myself when I tell my manager that I want to resign. Im not sure and am worried that it would reflect on me badly.

Comment: @joe yes thanks. I jusz graduated and nooo clue about corporate world plus I am a science graduate who didnt plan to work but study but things didnt work out so had to work. This is a useful experience too

Comment: Don't you have to take insane amount of exams to be certified as an actuary? Can't you just start working toward those level of exams?

Comment: No in my workmates are math majors who just graduated. The bosses i think do but assistants dont require that. I really envy them st least they used their education on their place.

Comment: There could be benefits to staying at your job and making the most of your free time, given that you’re [a clerk with an aptitude for science](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Albert_Einstein).

Answer (score 5):

The standard advice is to always wait until you have an other offer in hand before you resign your current one; this way, at the very least, you still have a paycheck while you look for other jobs. With that said, any and all hiring managers will definitely ask you why you are leaving your job after such a short period of time, and any damage to your reputation will be based off your answer to that question. If you answer it with anything that sounds like you are badmouthing your current employer, you are likely not to be viewed as a good candidate; hiring managers will likely think, "He's got so many negative things after working there for a *week*, how petty is this guy?" However, if you instead simply state what you are looking for, and refrain from badmouthing your current employer, it shouldn't be too bad. Something like, "I am looking for a position where I can make use of my math skills. In taking my current job, I had believed that I would be able to move into a position that allows me to do so, but I've been told that is not the case. As such, I'm applying for new positions." Not too many people will be worried about one job that lasts such a short time, especially at the beginning of your career. It's only when you make a habit out of job-hopping that your reputation will take a serious hit.

Comment: Thanks to this. I have this probation that says tht I have to finish 30 days upon resignantion and will confirm to my agency HR. I know what I did was stupid but served as lesson